# How do I build a commuting route that includes driving, public transit, and walking?

Tags: google-maps

I've noticed that [My Maps](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) is back in Google Maps. My primary interest is creating a route with the following itinerary:

1. Start from my "Home" location
2. Drive to a public transit location
3. Take the public transit to another location
4. Walk to my "Work" location

I was under the impression that I would be able to do this using the My Maps tool, but when creating directions, there are only three visible options and public transit is not among them.

[image: Transportation mode options]

Is there any way to do this in Google Maps?

Comment: One of the limitations of Google Maps is that if you select Public Transit, it makes your entire route public transit. I'd like to be able to see my driving commute to the light rail instead of being told to take a bus to it.

Comment: Can this be done in Google Maps, without using My Maps? If so, that'd be the answer I'm looking for.